# Unauthorized error when posting data in Azure Eventhub

Tags: c#, azure

I am doing a POC on sending data to Azure event hub using C#. The data will be posted over http unlike the Eventhub client. As per the requirements I cam creating a SAStoken to be embedded in http header. However when posting I get 501, Unauthorized access error. Not sure where I am going wrong. Here is the code that I have written

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendDataUsingHttp()
        {

            // Namespace info.
            var serviceNamespace = "myeventhubs";
            var hubName = "eventhub1";
            var url = string.Format("{0}/publishers/{1}/messages", hubName, 1);
            //var url = string.Format("{0}/messages", hubName);
            var baseUri = new 
             Uri(string.Format("https://{0}.servicebus.windows.net/" 
                          ,  serviceNamespace));
            var SharedAccessKeyName = "All";
            var SharedAccessKey = "<shared access key>";
            var sasToken = 
            createSasToken(baseUri.ToString(),SharedAccessKeyName, 
                           SharedAccessKey);
            var evtData = new
            {
                Temperature = new Random().Next(20, 50)
            };

            var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(evtData);
            // Create client.
            var httpClient = new HttpClient
            {
                BaseAddress = baseUri
            };


            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new 

            System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue   
             ("SharedAccessSignature", sasToken); 

           var content = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8);
           content.Headers.ContentType = new 
             System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage result = null;
            try
            {
                result = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            return result;
        }

         private static string createSasToken(string baseUri, string keyName, 
         string key)
        {
            TimeSpan sinceEpoch = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
            var week = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
            var expiration = Convert.ToString((int)sinceEpoch.TotalSeconds + 
            week);
            string stringToSign = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(baseUri) + "\n" + 
            expiration;
            HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key)); //--
            var signature = 
            Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( 
            stringToSign)));
            var sasToken = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                   "SharedAccessSignature sr={0}&sig={1}&se={2}&skn={3}", 
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(baseUri), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(signature), 
            expiration, keyName);
            return sasToken;
}
```

**result**

> {StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1,
>   Content:    System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: {
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked Strict-     Transport-Security:
>   max-age=31536000 Date: Sun, 17 Jun 2018 08:35:43 GMT     Server:
>   Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
>   }} Content: {System.Net.Http.StreamContent} Headers:
>   {Transfer-Encoding:   chunked Strict-Transport-Security:
>   max-age=31536000 Date: Sun, 17 Jun 2018   08:35:43 GMT Server:
>   Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

Comment: You can always edit your question to add more info without write a comment to add something new.

Comment: Have you solved this issue, do you need further assistance?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `createSasToken` method, it would generate the authorization header value with the following format:

```
Authorization: SharedAccessSignature sr={0}&sig={1}&se={2}&skn={3}
```

For your request, you also specify the following code:

```
System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("SharedAccessSignature", sasToken);
```

Using Fiddler to capture the network traces, you would find that your authorization header value in your sent request would look like this:

```
Authorization: SharedAccessSignature SharedAccessSignature sr={0}&sig={1}&se={2}&skn={3}
```

For your code, you need to adjust the format of your `sasToken` under the `createSasToken` method.

Moreover, the `baseUri` parameter of `createSasToken` method needs to be the full request path you are requesting. So you need to modify the related code under `SendDataUsingHttp` for generating the token as follows:

```
var sasToken =createSasToken(baseUri+url, SharedAccessKeyName, SharedAccessKey);
```